# [cocos2d]using CCSprite from HelloWorldLayer in other classes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

```
NSLog(@"lets test if this is called (before)");

HelloWorldLayer *helloWorldLayer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
//calling HelloWorldLayer  

id moveup = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(0, 5)];
[helloWorldLayer.player runAction:moveup];

NSLog(@"lets test if this is called (after)");
```

so basically I wrote this code and NSLogs are working fine but my player sprite is not moving... i don't think the code (CCMoveBy) is wrong. so First I thought its not calling HelloWorldLayer so I tried this.

I put this code in my other class.

```
HelloWorldLayer *helloWorldLayer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
//calling HelloWorldLayer  

[helloWorldLayer moveMyCharacter];
```

and this code in my HelloWorldLayer

```
-(void)moveMyCharacter
  NSLog(@"MOVE UP");

id moveup = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(0, 5)];
[_player runAction:moveup];
```

and the NSLog worked, but the character is not moving...

I need some help :(

Comment: You seem to be moving your character by 5 pixels in 1/6 of a second. Would you even notice such a small fast move? Try moving it slower and farther.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling this? By calling `[HelloWorldLayer node]`, you are creating a new layer every time this code is run. Unless you add this new layer to a scene, you won't see anything change. You probably want to get a reference to the layer you already have instead of creating a new one.

Comment: oh so I should change it to the specific layer that contains my player sprite?